# Gravity is not set on Relative Layout

Tags: android-layout

I am tackling relativeLayout problem in my application.
I take one image and button. I want to make button is bottom of the image but is not set.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ImageButton android:src="@drawable/layout_logo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/image" />

<Button android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:drawableBottom="@id/image"
        android:gravity="bottom" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RelativeLayout` uses `android:layout_above` and `android:layout_below` to position elements with regard to others.  Changing your `android:gravity="bottom"` to `android:layout_below="@id/image"` should fix this.